# Accessing Solr facet_ranges via Solrj

Tags: java, solr, facet, solrj, faceted-search

Maybe it is already to late, but I am struggling around with [Solr's Facet Ranges](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Facet_by_Range). I can execute the query via Solrj, but I do not understand how to retrieve the results via Solrj. The [QueryResponse](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/QueryResponse.html) object doesn't not give me the getter-methods for the ranges, does it?

E.g. the resulting XML looks like this:

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries"/>
<lst name="facet_fields"/>
<lst name="facet_dates"/>
<lst name="facet_ranges">
<lst name="my_field">
<lst name="counts">
<int name="2010-06-01T00:00:00Z">0</int>
<int name="2010-06-02T00:00:00Z">0</int>
<int name="2010-06-03T00:00:00Z">0</int>
...
```

and i want to get the data in counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the QueryResponse.getFacetRanges() method is what you want, but this is only available in very recent versions of SolrJ I think; 3.4.0 has it, but some earlier versions did not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was on 3.3.0 and now using 3.4.0 and I can access the counts via e.g. `queryResponse.getFacetRanges().get(0).getCounts()`

Answer (score 3):

Please see the SolrJ Example tests in [SolrExampleTests.java](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/solr/solr-3.3.0/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrExampleTests.java.html#line.150) line #150 for an example of how to retrieve facetQuery results.

Also looks like there is `getFacetQueries()` on the QueryResponse that returns a `Map<String,Integer>` that I would guess contains the facet ranges and their counts. You can see the source at [QueryResponse.getFacetQueries()](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/QueryResponse.html#getFacetQuery%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The query I make is not a facet query, but a facet range query. So the *getFacetQuery()* returns an empty result.